# Placing a Label and TextBox to the NW

Tags: python, tkinter

[How I Wanted the outcome to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUuzM.png)I want to place a `Label` and `TextBox` in the NW corner next to my Frame that's located in the NE corner.

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXVcj.png)

I tried to place a Label and a `TextBox` in the upper NW corner next to my `Frame` that's located in the upper NE corner.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()
root.title()
root.iconbitmap()
root.geometry("400x400")
root["bg"] = "Cyan"

LabelXP1 = Label(bg='Cyan',
             width=10,
             height=1,
             text=f"XPATH 1:")
LabelXP1.pack(anchor= NW)
xpath1 = Text(root,width= 20, height= 1)
xpath1.pack(anchor= NW)

LabelXP2 = Label(bg='Cyan',
             width=10,
             height=1,
             text=f"XPATH 2:")
LabelXP2.pack(anchor= NW)
xpath2 = Text(root,width= 20, height= 1)
xpath2.pack(anchor= NW)

list_frame = Frame(root, background="Cyan")
list_frame.pack(anchor= NE)
Label1 = Label(list_frame, background='Cyan',
          width=6,
          height=1,
          text="Urls: 0")
Label1.pack(anchor= N)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(list_frame, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbarh = Scrollbar(list_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)

listbox = Listbox(list_frame, background="Cyan", width=20,     yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

scrollbarh.config(command=listbox.xview)
scrollbarh.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

listbox.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this is close to what you're looking for. I created a new `Frame` called `input_frame` that now serves as the container for the two text inputs and their labels. I also fixed an issue with the `listbox.xscrollcommand` being set to the incorrect scrollbar.

Lastly, I changed `from tkinter import *` to `import tkinter as tk` which is considered best practice. Star imports can lead to namespace pollution and cause issues. Instead, do it this way and just prefix things accordingly with `tk.` (like `tk.filedialog`, wherever you're using that)

Also, capitalized names like `Label1` or `LabelXP1` are typically reserved for classes in Python, so you might want to change them in order to adhere to style convention (it won't break anything, but it goes against [PEP8](https://pep8.org)

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title()
root.iconbitmap()
root.geometry("400x400")
root["bg"] = "Cyan"

input_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='cyan')
input_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT)
LabelXP1 = tk.Label(
    input_frame,
    bg='Cyan',
    width=10,
    height=1,
    text=f"XPATH 1:"
)
LabelXP1.pack(anchor=tk.NW)
xpath1 = tk.Text(input_frame ,width=20, height= 1)
xpath1.pack(anchor=tk.NW)

LabelXP2 = tk.Label(
    input_frame,
    bg='Cyan',
    width=10,
    height=1,
    text=f"XPATH 2:"
)
LabelXP2.pack(anchor=tk.NW)
xpath2 = tk.Text(input_frame, width= 20, height= 1)
xpath2.pack(anchor=tk.NW)

list_frame = tk.Frame(root, background="Cyan")
list_frame.pack(anchor=tk.NE)
Label1 = tk.Label(
    list_frame,
    background='Cyan',
    width=6,
    height=1,
    text="Urls: 0"
)
Label1.pack(anchor=tk.N)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(list_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scrollbarh = tk.Scrollbar(list_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)

listbox = tk.Listbox(
    list_frame,
    background="Cyan",
    width=20,
    yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, 
    xscrollcommand=scrollbarh.set  # this was set to 'scrollbar' so I fixed it
)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

scrollbarh.config(command=listbox.xview)
scrollbarh.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

listbox.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [JRiggles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8512262/jriggles) my approach was also to put both the left and the right elements into their own `frame` but i placed them with `grid` instead of `pack` which I find more intuitive for horizontal allignment.

I further refactored your code into a OOP approach which is more clear and structured for this kind of project.

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Text, Scrollbar, Listbox, VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL, RIGHT, BOTTOM, Y, X


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Scraper by: XXX')
        self.iconbitmap()
        self.geometry('400x400')
        self['bg'] = 'Cyan'
        self.path_frame = Frame(self, background='Cyan')
        LabelXP1 = Label(self.path_frame, bg='Cyan', width=10, height=1, text='XPATH 1:')
        LabelXP1.pack()
        xpath1 = Text(self.path_frame, width=20, height=1)
        xpath1.pack()
        LabelXP2 = Label(self.path_frame, bg='Cyan', width=10, height=1, text='XPATH 2:')
        LabelXP2.pack()
        xpath2 = Text(self.path_frame, width=20, height=1)
        xpath2.pack()
        self.list_frame = Frame(self, background='Cyan')
        Label1 = Label(self.list_frame, background='Cyan', width=6, height=1, text='Urls: 0')
        Label1.pack()
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.list_frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        scrollbarh = Scrollbar(self.list_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        listbox = Listbox(self.list_frame, background='Cyan', width=20,
                          yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarh.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        scrollbarh.config(command=listbox.xview)
        scrollbarh.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        listbox.pack(pady=20)
        self.path_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(0, 10))
        self.list_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, I ended up fixing it using .PLACE. had to edit a few lines of code and mess with the X and Y axis to get er done! Love this site! Lots of helpful peeps and useful INFO.

    .place(relx = 1,
                   x =-163,
                   y = 85,
                  anchor= NE)

Comment: Good for you! Consider accepting @JRiggles answer if it helped.

Comment: @Jan_B `grid` is also a good option, but I personally find `pack` easier to use :) to each their own! Bonus points for OOP as well